# Run bash script using PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pycharm

I have a python project and inside the project, I have a bash script to upload to a server. I usually run this bash script in my terminal using

```
./bash_script.sh
```

I would like to know if it's possible to do this using PyCharm?

Comment: Why would you need to use `source` for this kind of  script? `source` is only needed if the script needs to modify the current shell's environment.

Comment: my bad I didn't mean source, just edited post.

Comment: `PyCharm` has a built-in terminal where you can run commands.

Comment: If you're asking whether there's a way to make the `Deployment` menu run this script automatically, I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add Bash Run/Debug configuration in PyCharm

[image]

Just go to the Edit configuration the Ctrl+Shift+A hotkey and find it by typing Run/Debug, like this

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow remote interpreter path in the Bash configuration file, right?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by Bash configuration file?

Comment: the Bash Run/Debug configuration that you refer to in your first line

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. I'm not entirely sure because I never tried to do that but technically you should be able to use it with the remote interpreter if by remote you mean ssh interpreter, since in that mode IDE runs scripts on the remote machine. But in this case, you would specify `remote interpreter path` as if it was local to the script you are running.
I hope that helps. Let me know if not.

Comment: No that doesn't work because the remote (SSH) interpreter is only valid to python scripts. The bash run configuration dialogue has its own interpreter field and, unlike in the python script run config dialogues, you cannot select ssh interpreters there. When you have the ssh interpreter selected for the project, this is the default for the python files but bash files still run locally. So the upload bash to server and run from remote terminal is the only way

Comment: Which version Pycharm is this?

Comment: I don't see the Bash option in the latest Pycharm version (2019 3.4)

Answer (score 1):

Select  `View > Tool Windows > Terminal` from the main menu in Pycharm to open an embedded terminal.

You can configure options, like path to the shell you'd like to use and the start directory in `Preferences > Tools > Terminal`